# Approval process custom HTML email template with no header and multiple languages based on user

Tags: email-template, approval-process, customlabel

Approval process custom email template ( not Vfpage but salesforce HTML email template with no header) with multiple languages based on user. I know this is possible with VF pages but we would like to use configurable email template for business using salesforce standard HTMl email template and use it for Approval process. As we have to use it for different countries like China, France etc.

Is it possible to achieve using the salesforce email templates ? and what is the best way to do this requirement.

Comment: Do you mean "Visualforce Email Template", which is not the same as "Vfpage" (Visualforce Page)? What is your opposition to using this feature?

Comment: I think it'd be helpful to know what your approval process currently looks like? Do you have separate processes for different languages? What have you tried? It seems you're certain you can do it in VF email template, but why do you think you cannot do it in html email template?

Comment: @sfdcfox: As I already have multiple approval process and now we are extending the functioanlity to new country which of different langauge, so thinking if I can acheive using existing HTML tempkates.